# VS Code color customization not being applied in settings.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes, dark-theme

I've switching a few colours around from the Github Dark them to meet my preferences. When it comes the module imports and the "self" keyword for classes, the colour stays the default theme colour no matter what I try. Is there something overwriting my changes or am I missing something stupid?

settings.json

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Shayn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe",
  "python.formatting.provider": "none",
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-darker",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.background": "#252323"
  },

  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.type.module.python", // change not implemented
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#7EBDFF"
        }
      },
      {
            "scope": "variable.language.special.self.python",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#7EBDFF" // change not implemented
            }
        },
      {
        "scope": ["variable.parameter", "comment"],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "keyword.control.try-except.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#e06c75"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.function",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#7EBDFF"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.type.class",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#7EBDFF"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.begin",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#98c379"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.end",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#98c379"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "string.quoted.single",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#98c379"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: if you have the Python extension installed, it's probably because semantic highlighting is taking higher priority over TextMate-based highlighting. You should use the token scope inspector tool and figure out what semantic token selector you should use instead.

Comment: i would be interested in this answer too...

Answer (score 0):

For Python, the scope for the "self" keyword is `variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python`,
and for module names in import statements, it's `entity.name.import.python`.

You can use the following codes to set it:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    // ...

    {
      "scope": "variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#7EBDFF" 
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": "entity.name.import.python",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#7EBDFF" 
      }
    },

    // ...
  ]
},
```

It will be able to be displayed in the following colors:

[image]